# TextView is showing only first characters intead of full string in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have `TextView` on which i am setting some Text "Welcome User", but in Android 4+ mobiles it is showing fine as in snapshot.

*First Screen if in Android 4.0.4 HTC mobile and it is showing "ITIL Foundation(Online Course)".*

[image: Android 4+ screen]

Whereas in Android 2.3 it is showing only first Character.

*Other screen Android 2.3.6 which is showing only "IT"*

[image: Android 2.3 screen]

And I searched, but no benefit. Please suggest.

I have worked for all version mobiles , I never faced such issues. Please suggest.

Here is my Xml Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header_logout"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/header_logo"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_course"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerlayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_paddingOverallLeftRight" >

        <com.util.TypefacedTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_userName"
            style="@style/style_Type1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text_numchapters"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Welcome" />

        <com.util.TypefacedTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_numchapters"
            style="@style/style_Type2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_course"
        android:background="@color/color_seperator" />

    <com.util.BounceListView
        android:id="@+id/list_enrolledcourses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:listSelector="@color/color_listviewselection"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_progressinfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        layout="@layout/layout_progress"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Formatting is not done properly so apology for this.

Comment: strange ... can you post the whole xml layout ?

Comment: could you please use LinearLayout for handle issue Part beacause I also never faced such kind of issue

Comment: Thanks for ur interest... I have added complete xml layout.

Comment: Thanks A M. I tried with LinearLayout as well but no success. I also never faced such issue.

Comment: Sorry I have also no idea ...

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue